# Trying to call a specific GET method on my WebAPI, but getting HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm making a call to `http://localhost/AppTools.WebAPI/api/BulletinBoard/GetMessagesForApp/AppName`, but it's returning a 404 error.  I think this has to do with routing, but I'm not sure.

Here's the Web API method inside my BulletinBoard controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMessagesForApp(string id)
        {
            // get current, valid messages
            var messages = (from i in db.BulletinBoards 
                            where i.AppId == id &&
                            DateTime.Today >= i.DisplayFrom &&
                            DateTime.Today <= i.DisplayTo &&
                            i.IsActive == true
                            select new 
                            {
                                Message = i.Message,
                                IntervalId = i.IntervalId,
                                Interval = i.Interval.IntervalDescription,
                                Timeout = i.Timout,
                            })
            .ToList();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, messages);
            return response;
}
```

Here's my RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

The standard `Get()` and `Get(int id)` work fine, I didn't change the method name or signatures.  `Get()` returns a complete list of records, `Get(int id)` returns a specific record.  I want `GetMessagesByApp(string id)` to return a list of records specific to a certain AppName.  Can you tell why this isn't working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here's my RouteConfig.cs:

The `RouteConfig.cs` file is used to define the routes for your ASP.NET MVC controllers. Those have absolutely nothing to do with the routes used by your Web API controllers. They are defined in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

So make sure you have declared your routes in the proper place:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiWithActionName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Notice that I have added a custom route before the default one which will allow you to achieve the desired url pattern.

And then you could have the following controller action which will work fine:

```
// GET /api/controllername
// GET /api/controllername/get
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    ...
}

// GET /api/controllername/get/123
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    ...
}

// GET /api/controllername/GetMessagesForApp/abc
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMessagesForApp(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but just out of curiosity, why is RouteConfig.cs included in a WebAPI project?

Comment: Because what you created is not a Web API project but an ASP.NET MVC project template that could be used to host Web API. You could have created an empty ASP.NET application (recommended) and then setting the things you only need.

Comment: `RouteConfig.cs` is exclusively for configuring ASP.NET routes whereas `WebApiConfig.cs` can be used for any Web API related configuration, including Web-API-specific routes, Web API services, and any other Web API settings.